# Casting a list of a primitive type to a IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, casting, primitive-types

in my C# program, I need to cast an object to a `IEnumerable<object>`. All I know about that object is, that it is a list (Type.IsGenericType):

```
IEnumerable<object> iEnu = myObject as IEnumerable<object>;

if (iEnu != null)
  foreach (object o in iEnu)
    // do stuff
```

As long as the type of the list is not a primitiv, it works fine, as all classes inherit from object. But primitives doesn't. Therefore, the cast to `IEnumerable<object>` returns null. I'd need to cast to `IEnumerable<int>`, if it's a list of integer, to `IEnumerable<bool>` if it's a list of booleans and so on. Naturally, i want just one generic cast.

Any idea, what to do to get the primitive lists as well?

Comment: try using the 'type' dynamic instead of object

Comment: Why not use `IEnumerable` for all cases?

Comment: @Maarten: Because I did not know that this works :P

@ prizm1: it doesn't work with dynamic

Thanks for the answers and the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`; although an `int[]` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<object>`, it *does* implement `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable enumerable = myObject as IEnumerable;

if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach (object o in enumerable)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to work with objects just use `IEnumerable`. But if you need to cast your object to `IEnumerable` of some concrete type, you may use `Enumerable.Cast<T>` Linq extension method.

[msdn Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Object obj = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
IEnumerable collection = obj as IEnumerable;
IEnumerable<int> integers = collection.Cast<int>();
foreach(int i in integers)
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
```